# Regarding Usage of Apache Cassandra along with Stratio or Datastax

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, stratio

1. From query performance wise I could not find any benchmark comparisons. 
   Found an issue GitHub which says Stratio is 10 times less performant than Datastax. Issue: https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/52.  Is the reported issue exceptional case? Dow both of them have a comparable performance on search queries?
2. If I started using Apache Cassandra along with Stratio's Lucene plugin, down the line in future can we seamlessly migrate to Datastax Cassandra like how we can upgrade to Apache Cassandra to DSE? If so any points to note down?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the point 1 - I don't have experience with Stratio, but want to mention that DSE Search heavily optimize the query path in multi-machine cluster, and this could be the reason for better performance.

For point 2 - it should be possible to migrate from OSS Cassandra to DSE, but everything depends on version that is used (see below).  One step before migration should include dropping of Stratio indices, then perform actual migration to DSE, and then create search indices.

Regarding versions - 2.1 could be migrated to DSE 4.8 & then migrated to 5.x, 2.2 should be migrated to Cassandra 3.x, and then migrated to DSE.  There is the [upgrade guide for this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdCstarToDSE.html) in DSE documentation.